# Chrome bug or bootstrap bug: Bootstrap dropdown jumps to its 'href' on click in chrome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

Have you had this problem:

When you click a Bootstrap(current version 3.3.6) dropdown menu, it will expand but at the same time jumps to a place specified in its `href`. I have this problem only on chrome (current version 51) in `Windows 7` only.

Even the official example has the problem to me.

See:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns

If I click `dropdown`, it jumps to the anchor "#" which is the top of page.

I have a way to work around it, but seems not beautiful.

```
<script>
$(".bs-example .dropdown a.dropdown-toggle").removeAttr("href").css("cursor","pointer");
</script>
```

Hope anyone can explain why it behaves like this and how to solve it elegantly.

Comment: No bug for me on latest on OSX

Comment: Load your browser in incognito mode, does it occur?

Comment: @epascarello No this problem in incognito mode. Dropdown just expands. Could you explain a bit?

Comment: @epascarello Thank you for your hints of incognito mode where extensions are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, let me explain it myself.
It's not a bug of chrome nor a bug of bootstrap.
It's a bug of one of my extension called ["拖拽搜索"(dragging search)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E6%8B%96%E6%8B%BD%E6%90%9C%E7%B4%A2/pikkaahnnohhoileadgipnfcklbalemk?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)
Since I synchronized my chrome extensions, I met this problem on all my laptops and desktops, which made me think it a common problem.

The extension is used mainly to help user search text from a web page by dragging it to right (search in baidu.com) or left (search in google.com). So it adds an event listener for dragging operation.

However, it has another designed intention to lift restrictions of the original page, such as select/copy/right-click actions.
To achieve this it adds event listeners to every kinds of mouse action and make the default response available by making `event.returnValue = true`;

a clip of the code:

```
    document.ondragstart = function () {
        event.returnValue = true;
        return (true);
    };
    document.oncontextmenu = function () {
        event.returnValue = true;
        return (true)
    };
    document.onselectstart = function () {
        event.returnValue = true;
        return (true)
    };
    document.onclick = function () {
        event.returnValue = true;
        return (true)
    };
    document.onmousedown = function () {
        event.returnValue = true;
        return (true)
    };
    document.onmouseup = function () {
        event.returnValue = true;
        return (true)
    };
    document.onbeforecopy = function () {
        return (true)
    };
    document.onbeforecut = function () {
        return (true)
    };
    document.oncopy = function () {
        event.returnValue = true;
        return (true)
    };
```

It is clear why my drop-down (and also tab) jumps away on click.
The bootstrap drop-down and tab uses `<a>`tag with `href`. 
The default behavior is to jump to the `href`, which is prevented by Bootstrap.
The extension add the default behavior back.

I decide to keep the extension but only keep the selection and dragging events. The result is good.

By the way, any one can tell how Bootstrap prevents the default behavior of `<a>` in drop down and tab?